# how to j-query append not calling function of j-query?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I want to call the function of j query the function given below .

```js
 $('#add_attri').click(function(){
      i++;  
      $('#attri').append('

<select class="form-control" name="attri_select" id="attri_select2">
<option value="">Select</option>@foreach($product_attri as $attri) 
<option value="{{$attri->id}}">{{$attri->name}} </option> @endforeach
</select>');

});
```

here on select the on click function call but not working.

Comment: you can generate js using php but not vice versa.. You need to generate js using php, you will be able to use loop as well then.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Are you sure jQuery is loaded? did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @AakashTushar yes there is no errors

Answer (score 1):

Tested.

Just change `'` to `

```
 $('#add_attri').click(function(){
      i++;  
      $('#attri').append(`

<select class="form-control" name="attri_select" id="attri_select2">
<option value="">Select</option>@foreach($product_attri as $attri) 
<option value="{{$attri->id}}">{{$attri->name}} </option> @endforeach
</select>`);

});
```

I tested this html and that works fine:

```
 $('#add_attri').click(function(){
      $('#attri').append(`
<select class="form-control" name="attri_select" id="attri_select2">
<option value="">Select</option></select>`);
});
```